# Fulltext search not returning expected results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am experimenting with SQL Server full text search.

I have a simple Categories table with Id as the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [CategoryName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
)
```

My Query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 FREETEXTTABLE (Category, CategoryName, 'music') AS F
 INNER JOIN  Category C ON F.[Key] = C.Id
ORDER BY F.Rank DESC
```

This returns me several records with the word music in them, but it does NOT return any record with word ‘musical’.

Although, it can be said that the string being searched is not very big and using the LIKE operator will resolve it. I would like to use fulltext search because this simple example is going to be extended to include other tables and fileds.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716748/mysql-full-text-search-with-partial-words

Comment: The link given is about full text search using MySQL database. My question is about SQL Server database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match prefixes, you could use containstable instead of freetexttable and include a wildcard on your search term: 'music*'

Comment: As per your suggestion, I tried this query
SELECT *  
FROM 
 CONTAINSTABLE (Category, CategoryName, 'music*') AS F 
 INNER JOIN  Category C ON F.[Key] = C.Id 
ORDER BY F.Rank DESC 

Gives the same result. Just the ranking is different

Comment: My bad on the syntax. Try it as '"music*"' (That's single quotes on the outer, double quotes on the inner).