# What's a good way to store keywords in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, search, autocomplete, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL full text search with partial words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716748/mysql-full-text-search-with-partial-words)

I have a search feature on a website I'm working on (basically a directory website with business listings) that uses MySQL's FULL TEXT searching. Nothing fancy and it works reasonably well.

What I'm wanting to do is create an autocomplete search input on the site that will automatically show keywords as you type. So if I type "plu", plumbers, plumbing, pluto, etc.

For me to accomplish that, do I need to store keywords for each business listing? I've seen scripts that will extract keywords from an input. Or can I generate keywords from all listings in the database? Not really sure what the best want do this is.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the keywords are categorized?

Comment: No, they aren't. When I search the database, I use MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE for the column 'details', which I have a FULLTEXT KEY assigned to.

Comment: Tip: Your users are probably satisfied with you batching the keyword creation.  What I want to say is that you don't have to recalculate new keywords with every save.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716748/mysql-full-text-search-with-partial-words

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks, Juan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer shows you how to do searching on substrings

[MySQL full text search with partial words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716748/mysql-full-text-search-with-partial-words)

```
(MATCH (a.article_name) AGAINST ('MySQL*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

It only supports subqueries matching the beginning of keywords, according to that answer